# How to create bulk articles by using php script?

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, database

I have seen this post and it was really helpful

> [Create categories, subcategories and articles using php](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5359/create-categories-subcategories-and-articles-using-php)

but I am not able to create articles by using same script.

I have modified the script but everytime its giving me this error

> Call to undefined method CategoriesHelper::validateCategoryId()

Is there any other way to create bulk articles or add data to the joomla #__content table??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also faced the similar issue once and I modified the code as following which worked for me. You also need to pass the `access` and `metadata` in the article parameters.

```
$article_data = array(
    'id' => 0,
    'catid' => 2,
    'title' => 'My article title',
    'alias' => 'my-article-alias',
    'introtext' => 'My intro text',
    'fulltext' => 'My full text',
    'state' => 1, //if you want to keep the article published else 0
    'alias' => 'my-article-alias',
    'state'=>1,
    'language' => '*',
    'access' => 1,
    'metadata' => json_encode(array('author' => '', 'robots' => ''))
);

$article_id = createArticle($article_data);
if(!$article_id){
    echo "Article create failed!";
}
else{
    echo 'Article created';
}

function createArticle($data)
{
    $data['rules'] = array(
        'core.edit.delete' => array(),
        'core.edit.edit' => array(),
        'core.edit.state' => array(),
    );

    $basePath = JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.'/components/com_content';
    require_once $basePath.'/models/article.php';
    $article_model =  JModelLegacy::getInstance('Article','ContentModel');
    // or  $config= array(); $article_model =  new ContentModelArticle($config);
    if(!$article_model->save($data)){
        $err_msg = $article_model->getError();
        return false;
    }else{
        $id = $article_model->getItem()->id;
        return $id;
    }

}
```

> Note: For static, it will work only once as article article alias needs to be unique.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You can import data to the `#__articles` table in `phpMyAdmin` using a CVS import.

Note that the entries created in the `#__assets` table are not necessary to the stability of the website - we run many many Joomla websites where the articles have no associated entries in the `#__assets` table.